# Integration Testing with MSTest

Tags: c#, integration-testing, mstest, asp.net-web-api

Forgive my ignorance for i am a fairly new programmer let alone tester, my question deals with the testing of an API at my organization.  My task is to perform integration testing making sure that the API calls we consume in our web-app are returning the correct HTTP status codes.  In certain cases i am also confirming that the API actually has entered the data into the database.  I am using MSTest to run my tests through the Visual Studio Integrated Test Runner. The objective is to have a suite of tests that we can run along with our drop on a nightly basis.

Moving on....

The example i am using deals with several PatronMessage api calls.

The system is able to

1. Return a list of system defined messages
2. Return a list of patron specific messages
3. Add a new message to a patron
4. Modify a patron message
5. Delete a patron message

The way i have written the code, i have an xml file with attributes apiObject(PatronMessages) and objectAction(GetSystemDefined-Successful) among other atrributes but these are used for test identification purposes.

I also have an abstract class called TestCase which has several implemented, virtual, and abstract methods.  I then create a PatronMessagesTestCase class which extends TestCase and implements all the abstract and overrides some virtual methods from TestCase. The RunTest concrete method from TestCase is then passed apiObject and objectAction and returns test parameters from the xml file to run the test. This RunTest method return a boolean value indicating whether the test passed or not.

The issue im having is that the way that verification is for most of the tests is completely different.  I have a MakeDatabaseCall method which in PatronMessagesTestCase implements the abstract method for TestCase but this MakeDatabaseCall may or may not be different. For example:

For testing add new message i would check the database value for the highest message id and then perform the api call and then check the database value and confirm that the message id after the call is greater. While for a delete message test I might run the same test but check that the the database value is lower than the one previously checked.

I know i can add a switch and switch on the objectAction but then every method within my PatronMessagesTestCase would need to switch on objectAction and that seems wrong to me.

Once again moving on........

So yesterday i asked one of the senior developers for help and he suggested that i use an interface (ITestCase) to structure a testcase and then have a class (PatronAssociationsTestCase) which implements ITestCase and also create a test runner class which runs all of your testcases but i did a bit of that and i got kind of confused as to how that would help my situation(i really think it just made it worse. But here's my code, keep in mind that im pretty much trying to accomplish the same thing twice, just in two different spots in two different ways. Also keep in mind that this is not completed code so it might throw some errors(I started working and kind of got stuck on my thoughts)........

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LEAPIntegrationTestingFINAL
{
    public interface ITestCase
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> GetTestParams(string apiObject, string     objectAction);
        public string ConfigureURL(string objectAction);
        //public Dictionary<string, object> ConfigureRequestBody(Dictionary<string,     object> testParams); //<=-=-=-Some tests need to 
        public Dictionary<string, object> ExecuteRequest(Dictionary<string, object>     testParams);
        public Dictionary<string, object> ParseResponse(Dictionary<string, object>    responseValues);
         //public Dictionary<string, object> MakeDatabaseCall(Dictionary<string, object> testParams); //<=-=-=-Some tests need to
        public bool CompareData(Dictionary<string, object> databaseValues,    Dictionary<string, object> responseValues);
   }

public static class TestRunner 
{
    public static bool RunTest(ITestCase TestCase, string apiObject, string objectAction) 
    {
        bool comparisonValue = false;
        return comparisonValue;
    }
}

public class PatronAssociationsTestCase : ITestCase 
{

    public Dictionary<string, object> GetTestParams(string apiObject, string objectAction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ConfigureURL(string objectAction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> ConfigureRequestBody(Dictionary<string, object> testParams)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> ExecuteRequest(Dictionary<string, object> testParams)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> ParseResponse(Dictionary<string, object> responseValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> MakeDatabaseCall(Dictionary<string, object> testParams)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool CompareData(Dictionary<string, object> databaseValues,     Dictionary<string, object> responseValues)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestParameterFile>
<Messages action="GETSystemDefined-Succesful"
        method="GET" expectedReponseCode ="200"/>

<Messages action="AddPatronMessage-InvalidPatronID"             
         method = "POST" expResponseCode="404" requestBody="{&quot;MessageType&quot;:     101,&quot;MessageValue&quot;: &quot;This is a free text message for this patron!&quot;}"/>

</TestParameterFile>
```

This is the original way(i think better way) i had tried to implement and would like to incorporate an interface if possible

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LEAPIntegrationTestingFINAL
{
    public abstract class TestCase
    {
        public static string authorizationString
        {
            get
            {
                string statusCode;
                AppConfig.Change("D:\\SampleProjects\\LEAP\\LEAPIntegrationTestingFINAL\\LEAPIntegrationTestingFINAL\\TestingSuiteConfiguration.config");

                //Converting User credentials to base 64.
                string uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authURL"];
                string uname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
                string pword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
                string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", uname, pword);
                string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));
                string _cred = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", _enc);

                WebRequest authRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                authRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, _cred);
                authRequest.ContentLength = 0;
                authRequest.Method = "POST";


                //Creating and receiving WebResponse

                HttpWebResponse authResponse = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse();
                statusCode = Convert.ToString((int)authResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream responseStream = authResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> authResponseObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        string authJSON = sr.ReadLine();
                        sr.Close();
                        responseStream.Close();

                        //Deserialization of jSON object and creating authorization String
                        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        authResponseObject = jsSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(authJSON);
                        string AccessToken = authResponseObject["AccessToken"].ToString();
                        string AccessSecret = authResponseObject["AccessSecret"].ToString();
                        string authorizationString = "Authorization: PAS " + AccessToken + ":" + AccessSecret;
                        return authorizationString;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> testParams { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> responseValues { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> databaseValues { get; set; }
        public bool comparisonValue { get; set; }




        public bool RunTest(string apiObject, string objectAction) 
        {
            bool comparisonValue = false;
            this.testParams = GetTestParams(apiObject, objectAction);
            this.url = RootURLBuilder.Build();
            this.url = ConfigureURL(this.url);
            #region ConfigRequestBody
            if (this.testParams.ContainsKey("requestBody"))
            {
                this.testParams = ConfigureRequestBody(this.testParams);
            }
            #endregion
            this.responseValues = ExecuteRequest(this.testParams);
            this.responseValues = ParseResponse(this.responseValues);
            #region MakeDatabaseCall
            if (this.testParams.ContainsKey("query"))
            {
                this.databaseValues = MakeDatabaseCall(this.testParams);
            }
            #endregion
            this.comparisonValue = CompareData(this.databaseValues, this.responseValues);
            return comparisonValue;
        }
        private Dictionary<string, object> GetTestParams(string apiObject, string objectAction) 
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> testParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            return testParams;
        }
        public abstract string ConfigureURL(string objectAction);
        public abstract Dictionary<string, object> ConfigureRequestBody(Dictionary<string,object> testParams);
        public Dictionary<string, object> ExecuteRequest(Dictionary<string, object> testParams) 
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> responseValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            string requestBody = null;
            string httpVerb = this.testParams["method"].ToString();
            #region requestBody = this.testParams["requestBody"].ToString();
            if (this.testParams.ContainsKey("requestBody"))
            {
                requestBody = this.testParams["requestBody"].ToString();
            }
            #endregion
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(this.url);
            req.Headers.Add(authorizationString);
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Method = httpVerb;

            if (requestBody != null)
            {
                req.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
                using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    byte[] reqBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
                    reqStream.Write(reqBodyBytes, 0, reqBodyBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            else
                req.ContentLength = 0;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                string responseJSON;
                int statusCode = (int)resp.StatusCode;
                string statusMessage = resp.StatusDescription;

                Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respStream);
                responseJSON = sr.ReadToEnd();
                respStream.Close();
                sr.Close();

                responseValues.Add("statusCode", statusCode);
                responseValues.Add("statusMessage", statusMessage);
                responseValues.Add("responseJSON", responseJSON);
            }
            return responseValues;

        }
        public virtual Dictionary<string, object> ParseResponse(Dictionary<string, object> responseValues)
        {

            Dictionary<string, object> parsedResponseJSON = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Dictionary<string, object> parsedResponse = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            string json = this.responseValues["responseJSON"].ToString();




            parsedResponse.Add("statusCode", this.responseValues["statusCode"]);
            parsedResponse.Add("statusMessage", this.responseValues["statusMessage"]);






            return parsedResponse;
        }
        public abstract Dictionary<string, object> MakeDatabaseCall(Dictionary<string, object> testParams);
        public abstract bool CompareData(Dictionary<string, object> databaseValues, Dictionary<string, object> responseValues);
    }

    public class PatronMessageTestCase : TestCase 
    {

        public override string ConfigureURL(string objectAction)
        {
            string url;

            switch (objectAction)
            {
                case "GETSystemDefined-Succesful":
                    url = this.url + "/patronmessages";
                    return url;
                default:
                    return "Not Found";
            }
        }

        public override Dictionary<string, object> ConfigureRequestBody(Dictionary<string, object> testParams)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override Dictionary<string, object> MakeDatabaseCall(Dictionary<string, object> testParams)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CompareData(Dictionary<string, object> databaseValues, Dictionary<string, object> responseValues)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

Finally..... The file which runs the tests and uses MSTest to control that

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace LEAPIntegrationTestingFINAL
{
    [TestClass]
    public class LEAPTestingSuite
    {        
        [TestMethod]
        public void MessagesTests()
        {
            PatronMessageTestCase MessagesTests = new PatronMessageTestCase();
            Assert.AreEqual(true, MessagesTests.RunTest("Messages", "GETSystemDefined-Succesful"));
        }



        [TestMethod]
        public void AssociationsTests() 
        {

            PatronAssociationsTestCase GETSystemDefined = new PatronAssociationsTestCase();
            Assert.AreEqual(true, TestRunner.RunTest());
        }
    }
}
```

There are a couple of more classes our there let me know if you need any of them...and just to recap, my primary goal is to make api calls and make sure that the response code returned matches the expectedResponseCode in the xml file.  I would also be able to optionally make a database call and confirm that some database value matches some data returned from the api call.  Also, my coworker suggested using an interface

Comment: What is your question / problem?

Comment: I would like to know what the better way of testing this would be. I have presented my first way of doing it but my PatronMessagesTestCase class will be full of switch statements.  A senior developer had mentioned using an interface and creating another class TestRunner which runs my interface implemented class PatronAssociationsTestCase.  I really dont know how to implement this, i tried but i dont even know if that solves my problem.

Comment: Then ask your senior co-worker to show you what he means.